# How is this not constructive? It is duplicate, but very constructive!

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, not-constructive, broken-windows

This question: [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/113547/561731) was closed by a mod for "non constructiveness"

But a question (that looks like a duplicate) is still all open ( [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22358/561731) ).

If [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22358/561731) is constructive, then [iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/113547/561731) is constructive, but a **duplicate**.

Why was it closed like it was, and should it be changed?

Comment: It has 43 Answers, and you *don't* see how it could cause extended discussion?

Comment: @raveturned 42 answers **ALL** community wiki.

Comment: the question that is "still all open" looks like a typical [broken window](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/broken-windows/info "what's this?") // *update* - it is closed now

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a perfect model of its guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128575) !

Comment: 2009 called, they want their confusion over the meaning of CW back.

Comment: @PopularDemand 1996 called, they want their joke back.

Comment: I suppose you're right @DjangoReinhardt, 2009 would have probably tweeted or texted instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's more because the other question was just as non-constructive as the one you're suggesting is a duplicate of it.

I've closed that question as "Not Constructive" as well.  *Both* questions have conflicting information (some saying yes, some saying no), as well as being *lists of things*.

So to answer your question, the other post *shouldn't* have been open as "Not Constructive" but that's been rectified now.